# Efficient EF Query using Where Clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

we want to filter out a View rows based on a list of values that are passed to that method.

```
public List<Model.View_RegOrgUserInfo> GetAdminInfoList(List<string> adminWwids)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var ctx = new Context())
                {
                  return ctx.View_RegOrgUserInfo.Where(x => adminWwids.Contains(x.WWID.Value.ToString())).ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                onboardingLogger.LogException(ex); throw ex;
            }
        }
```

The `adminWWIDs` is a list of string and `WWID` column in View is `int?` But we see a timeout exception here. The `adminWWIDs` list has around 10K items and view has around 200K rows
I am not sure what are we doing wrong and how do we make it efficient.

Exception:

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The wait operation timed out","ExceptionType":"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"
```

Comment: I'd suggest starting by looking at the generated SQL query. That being said, I suspext your conversion (`ToString()`) makes it impossible to use an index. And PSA: Don't use `throw ex` to rethrow, just use `throw` without an argument

Comment: Contains is not very efficient with anything other than small sets of data. How many items are in adminWwids? Also, why is adminWwids strings instead of ints? It would be better to convert them to ints rather than the ints to strings. Are you sure this is even executing in SQL on the DB? Can you do .Value or .ToString with entity framework? Not an efficient way to do so if you can.

Comment: It's the 10k items in adminWwids that is killing you. That's generating a giant where in statement.

Comment: I think thats the problem in here. This is an app thats passed on to me..I didn't write it in first place though.So I don't have control over why the `adminWWID` list is not int. I wanted to fix this.

Comment: when I convert the list of string into list of int, the query runs fine. Why is it so? why is it failing for strings but running fine for int even with contains.Overall whats the right way to do this?

Comment: As a personal rule, I avoid using where in (contains) for anything that I expect to have more than 100 values, and even that can go poorly. 10k can easily bring a smaller system down.

Comment: Probably because you're not relying on the db to handle the conversion. It needs to convert all 200k ids to strings and then perform a more costly string comparison. If you convert your list to ints, there should be a lot less for the DB to handle. Also if the ints are primary keys, you're able to take more advantage of that, rather than the converted to string versions.

Comment: Agreed, how should it be fixed in right way? without using contains

Comment: Typo in my above comment, should not be a not in that first sentence.

Comment: Sometimes contains is difficult to avoid, but if you're able, it's always always better to get the list of ids from somewhere within the db, and then join them to the table you're querying. This list of 10k ids, did they originate from the db?

Comment: This ids tha I want to compare are coming from one table in db which after post processing in code we filter and send to this view fr querying

Comment: Have you tried using SP and passing a comma separated string which can be converted to a table variable in SP?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your access to the database, how frequently the 10,000 list changes, and how often you are calling this, you might be able to load the 10,000 items into a temporary table in the database and then use an EF join to get the data that you want.

Of course, you could iterate through the 200,000 rows and use LINQ for objects to compare and find the data, but unless it's a tiny table and a local database, that would probably not be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

for the operation timeout exception it's because EF by default has 15 or 30 seconds timeout duration.

to make ipmprovements to your code:

1- add the below code so that your query finishes and won't throw an exception

```
ctx.Database.CommandTimeout = 3000;
```

2- It's always best practice to use async

3- use AsNoTracking()

```
await ctx.View_RegOrgUserInfo.Where(x => adminWwids.Contains(x.WWID.Value.ToString())).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

4- You can try converting the List into List inside the function and then

```
await ctx.View_RegOrgUserInfo.Where(
x => x.WWID != null &&
adminWwids.Contains(x.WWID)
).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

if the above approaches still does not satisfy you then you could try something like this:

```
    var parameters = string.Join("," , adminWwids); 
    var query = $"SELECT * FROM VIEW_REGORUSERINFO WHERE WWID IN (parameters);

    return await db.Database.SqlQuery<VIEW_REGORUSERINFO>(query).AsQueryable().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```